# jQuery delegate click handler to class method?

Tags: jquery

How can I make this work? I just want do call a call method once the user clicks the screen.
There seems to be an error right now. I don't get any feedback/log on click.

```
var App = {

    container : null,

    init : function(params) {
        this.container = params.container;
        $('html').on('click', $.proxy(this.nextImage, this));
    },

    nextImage : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.info("next image"); // no output yet
    }
}
```

I am calling it like;

```
new App.init({ container: null }):
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? It works for me; http://jsfiddle.net/z3m3Z/

Comment: are you loading jQuery before this script as you have used jQuery click event in your script.

Comment: Oh i wrote new App.init(…). It works without the "new"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App would need to be a function for it to work with new and it would have to be new App().Init. As it is, App is just an object

If you want App to be a 'class':

```
var App = function() {

    var container=null;

    var init = function(params) {
        this.container = params.container;
        $('html').on('click', $.proxy(this.nextImage, this));
    };

    var nextImage = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.info("next image"); // no output yet
    };

    return {
      init: init,
      nextImage: nextImage
    };
}
```

To use it: `new App().init(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I wrote `new App.init(…)`.

It works without the "new"